# Any tool, ide or whatever to search files where there are elements of a class o id?

Tags: html, linux, search

any tool, ide or whatever to search files where there are elements of a class o id? I would insert the class or the id to the search engine.

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many text editors will do that.

I personally use [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (windows) to search same text across multiple files.

You did not specify an operating system, so I can only recommend what I use.

---

Update:

[Here](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/find_replace_inter.html) is a tutorial on search/replace on multiple files for emacs.

Comment: @user248959 - answer updated. In the future, include "little" details like this in your question (or add a tag).